# Web 8 New Topology Manager publishing to wrong Database

Tags: web8, database, topology-manager

I've created a new Topology manager, new Discovery, Content and Deploy service as in the docs for a new site (in web 8).

I had an other site already set up on the same servers.
Everything seemed fine but when I make a new site and publish the for example the homepage. It get saved inside the broker database of the other side.

Is there any other config outside those of the services I've to change? Or what is causing the issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have two deployers running on the same machine, make sure their "incoming" folders are different.

Comment: Thanks for response.

I've checked and they seems to be correct inside Tridion_CD_Microservices\Staging\mysite\deployer\config\cd_storage_conf.xml
But indeed when publishing the .zip files get inside the incoming folders of the other website.

Comment: They need to point to different locations. If you have two deployers, make sure the incoming folder in cd_deployer_conf.xml points to different places. If both deployers are monitoring the same incoming folder, you will have unexpected results (like what you're seeing now)

Comment: Yes indeed but my deployers do point to different folders. 
I was wrong in my comment, they are indeed inside cd_deployer_conf.xml
Is it the deployer service that places the files inside the incoming folder or which service does this? Thanks a lot

Comment: The deployer has 2 sides to it - the receiver, and the actual deployer. The receiver part will store it in the incoming folder, and the deployer will pick it up from there. If you feel adventurous, you can actually decouple this and run the receivers on different machines (and load balanced and whatever). Anyway, maybe try stopping one of the deployers, publish, see if the result is as expected, then switch the active deployers, publish, etc, until you get to the bottom of it. Bottom line is that this should not be happening, so it must be your config.

Comment: Ok thanks for advice to try to stop one of them. Because if I stop the deployer of the other site, publishing fails at 'Transporting' so it seems it's using the wrong deploying service. I must have configured this wrong somewhere.

Comment: Maybe something with your CDEnvironment configuration, meaning the publisher is trying to send the content to the wrong deployer. Do you have different environments and purposes?

Comment: yes i'll check my CDEnvironment config. 
it seems it uses the wrong discovery service so also the wrong deployer service.
I've different environments and purposes. Thanks for your respons.

Answer (score 3):

Details are a little bit vague but I would start in your Deployer's config.  Go to your Deployers root directory and then inside the config and open the cd_storage_conf.  Confirm the details of your  configuration.

Example:

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" 
            Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">`
<Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
 <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
       <Property Name="serverName" Value="YourServerName" />
       <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
       <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
       <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
       <Property Name="password" Value="YourPassword" />
  </DataSource>
```

Comment: Also check you have registered the Deployer service with the Discovery and that your Publication, inside the CMS, has the correct Business Process Type setup.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
But in Tridion_CD_Microservices/mywebsite/deployer the cd_storage_conf is correct.
Also i've the correct Business Process Type setup and it the Deployer has the Discovery service registered.

`<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://servername:port/discovery.svc"`

And I've restarted my services and IIS.